# unable to select from drop-down with firefox (works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is be able to select from the drop-down menu without the accordion changing. This works in Chrome. However, when I was trying it in Firefox, it no longer worked.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fuLxu/) is my jsfiddle.

Why does this not work in Firefox?

I believe that it is this code that is causing the problem (dropdowns without the selectOne class work fine):

```
$(function () {
  $('.selectOne').click(function(){
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Just me or I can't get your fiddle's slider/accordion to work on Chrome nor Firefox..?

Comment: slider? You shouldn't see a slider. That was just placeholder text.

Comment: Horizontal accordion should work on both though.

Comment: It works, just have to scroll way over to see the other sections.

Comment: Ohh I knew I was missing something. Just spend 5 minutes desperately clicking the left-most one and nothing happened, now I see that it was just the already open one.

Comment: I've tried the fiddle on FF Nightly and it worked fine, when removing the `.selectOne` click handler it bugs the second `select`. I'll downgrade to FF stable to check again.

Comment: The `select`s don't work even if you remove the return false from the handler, interesting. It looks like a bug in the plugin honestly. Even though it is not reproduce-able on my non-stable release which makes it even more weird.

Comment: The dropdowns don't seem to like the CSS transform/rotate that is being applied. Ex: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pratie/G9vGN/)  I pulled in all CSS from the external file, the accordion content is overlapping but you can see that the dropdowns work. Try to re-structure your code and apply the transform to the `H2` text only, move `select`s out of the H2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the linked libraries.  Have you linked the plugin.  Accordian is a jQuery Plugin, not just jQuery.